# Ubuntu 14.04 stuck in login loop after update, nothing seems to help

Tags: 14.04, graphics, login, lightdm, gdm

I updated my ubuntu 14.04 after it was being unused for 4 months. The updating took enormously longer time than usual, and after that the computer was very slow. I rebooted the computer and now I cannot get past the login screen. When I login it immeaditely returns to the login screen.

I have checked the owner of .Xauthority, tried deleting it and tried installing gdm. Login still loops if I use gdm instead of lightdm. I have run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`, `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo apt-get update`, but apt-get doesn't complain anything or give any errors.

What to do?

Comment: Have your tried  'sudo unity-reset'

Answer (score 0):

You can reset your unity before trying to login Ctl + Alt + F1 login then try Ctl + Alt + F7  [install `unity-reset`](https://launchpad.net/~amith/+archive/ubuntutools/+build/3910667/+files/unity-reset_0.1-8_all.deb)

Installing unity-reset in tty:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool

sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

**To reset tweak tool**

```
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

Then type:

```
$ unity-reset
```

You can aslo try to reinstall the unity if this does not work with.
 `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Last option install new desktop from tty this option installs  **Gnome Desktop**

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Comment: `sudo unity-reset` gets me an error message: `sudo: unity-reset: command not found` and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` does not help. I'm still stuck at the login loop.

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: How can I install unity-reset? apt-get returns with E: Unable to locate package unity-reset

Comment: After logining on tty ctl alt f1 login then hit ctl alt f7 (may not work)

Comment: No, it's still at the login screen when I press ctrl-alt-f7 after logging in on tty

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue with Ubuntu desktop 15.10. My issue was related to nvidia graphics card driver. After installing the driver from ppa resolved my issue. I was also stuck with the login loop at the unity desktop at the time of start up. Could you please elaborate regarding your case? I know this answer may not be applicable in your case.

Comment: What information you need? How can I get the info? My graphics card is ATI Radeon HD 5770

Comment: Go to virtual console(Ctrl+Alt+F1) - you can still login to ubuntu(using your credentials) and then follow this page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver. When you are installing   graphics driver you need to stop lightdm(in case unity) and then go to XWindows(Ctrl+Alt+F7) again

Comment: Oh god, now I am in deep. After following the instructions about purging the propietary driver and rebooting, my computer does not boot at all. It gets stuck "Waiting for cryptswap" and skipping and manual recovery buttons do not work.